# Meteor - createContainer not rendering to React

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reactjs, meteor, ecmascript-6

I am trying to retrieve data from a mongo database dynamically, like when someone inserts something to a database it updates it automatically in the client side. First I used Tracker.autorun on main.js in the client folder and it works. I pass a prop into the root component when running "ReactDOM.render" and it renders. However, when I added routes I am no longer passing a component i am passing whole routes. So I tried running it on the component file and it doesn't work. So I tried using createContainer, I followed the docs on the meteor website but the data I am getting a "Uncaught ReferenceError: props is not defined" error. Please help me find what I am doing wrong. Thank you in advance.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Tracker } from 'meteor/tracker';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data'

import { Temp } from './../api/temp';

import Navigation from './Navigation';
import Readings from './Readings';


// Tracker.autorun(function () {
//   console.log(Temp.find().fetch());
//   });

export class App extends React.Component {

render() { 
return (
            <div>
             <Navigation/>
             <h1>HomePage</h1>
             <Readings temp={props.getData}/>
            </div>
        );
     }
  }

export default createContainer(() => {
  Meteor.subscribe('temp');
  return { 
      getData: Temp.find().fetch()
  };
}, App);
```

Answer (score 1):

`props` is not defined because it lives on the class instance, to be accessed with `this.props`. you can read up on es6 classes and react [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html).

You will find however, that by the time the component renders, your subscription is not ready yet. So use the subscription handle to test if it is ready and show a loader in the meantime.

```
export class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {ready, getData} = this.props;
    if (!ready) return (<div>loading...</div>);
    return (
      <div>
        <Navigation/>
        <h1>HomePage</h1>
        <Readings temp={getData}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default createContainer(() => {
  const handle = Meteor.subscribe('temp');
  return {
      ready: handle.ready(),
      getData: Temp.find().fetch()
  };
}, App);
```